# Laravel DB::table update record

Tags: php, pdo, laravel-4

I have this query

```
 DB::table('product_options')
        ->where('product_id', $id)
        ->where('size', $selected_size)
        ->update(array('stock' => WHAT TO PUT HERE));
```

In the update part where I've put WHAT TO UPDATE, what should I put here to decrease the number by 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `decrement` method. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates

```
 DB::table('product_options')
        ->where('product_id', $id)
        ->where('size', $selected_size)
        ->decrement('stock');
```

Comment: So I dont need the update method then just decrement? @slapyo

Comment: Yup, check out the link. You can pass the value you want to decrease by and you can also pass other columns to update if you need.

Comment: Yep always forgot about these little extra bits in Laravel, cheers dude